# Google Maps Android API v2 - I can't run the example from Google

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to test Gmaps example of Android developer from Android SDK Manager.

- The Google Play Service was imported as a Library.
- The libs folder was cleaned from the library project;
- The maps sample was imported;
- In project properties --> Android, I have the following configs:
- Google API's instead of standard Android;
- Library --> Google play services is green.

The errors that are presented:

1. The import com.google.android.gms.location cannot be resolved
2. The method setImage(BitmapDescriptor) is undefined for the type
   GroundOverlay
3. The method flat(boolean) is undefined for the type MarkerOptions,
4. and others methods undefined.

I'm newbie in Android development, so.. what is wrong?

Could someone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you have done all the right things. Have you tried cleaning all your projects and/or update the eclipse plugins? Is the Google Play Service library compiled correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you made changes in your `manifest`?What about the key which is to be registered in Google console and is to be declared in the manifest file?
Some permissions need to be declared in the manifest file like:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

and the key is to declared in meta data:

```
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="your key value" />
```